# PyQt4 Signals and Slots

Tags: pyqt4

I'm still learning Python and PyQt4, I just can't seem to get anything to display on my gui window when the "Harvest" button is pushed. I highlighted in bold my lack of knowledge on signals and slots.

Updated Code:

```
import sys, random, sqlite3, os
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from geodesic import Ui_MainWindow

class gameWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(gameWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        buttonHarvest = QPushButton("Harvest") #Create the harvest button - but QT Designer made it?
        buttonMining = QPushButton("Mining") # Create the mining button - but QT Designer made it?
        self.label = QLabel("Example") # Set the empty label that's not showing

        self.connect(buttonHarvest, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.skillHarvest) #Gets from def skillHarvest
        self.setWindowTitle("Geodesic")
        # Next -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.connect(buttonMining, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.skillMining) #Gets from def skillMining

    def skillHarvest(self):
        harvest = "You find some roots."
        self.label.setText(harvest)

    def skillMining(self):
        mining = "You found some gold."
        self.label.setText(mining)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
showWindow = gameWindow()
showWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
import sys, random, sqlite3, os
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from geodesic import Ui_MainWindow

class gameWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(gameWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        buttonHarvest = self.ui.buttonHarvest
        buttonMining = self.ui.buttonMining
        #showLabel = self.ui.label

        self.connect(buttonHarvest, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onButtonHarvest)
        # Next
        self.connect(buttonMining, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.onButtonMining)

    def onButtonHarvest(self):
        harvest = "You find some roots."
        showLabel = self.ui.label
        showLabel.setText(harvest)

    def onButtonMining(self):
        mining = "You found some gold."
        showLabel = self.ui.label
        showLabel.setText(mining)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
showWindow = gameWindow()
showWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems to me that the definition for the method "one" is badly indented.

on your sample, it has been declared as a subfunction of TestApp.**init**(), so from outside you can't call one(). try to unindent the definition of one() to make it a method of class TestApp.

Comment: I made a few changes to the code but it;s still not working. Everything loads fine and I can see the window with buttons attached. But still when the buttons are activated nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, for the connection of the signals to slots you could use the more "pythonic" form:

```
buttonHarvest.clicked.connect(self.onButtonHarvest)
buttonMining.clicked.connect(self.onButtonMining)
```

It goes like this:

```
widget.signal.connect(slot)
```

You may find more info [here](http://pysnippet.blogspot.com/2010/01/new-style-pyqt-signals-and-slots.html)